# i'm having a problem with adding a simple remember me function in php log in my page?

Tags: php, html, web, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to add a simple remember me function to my login.php code:

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION["comp"])){
        header("location view.php");//to redirect to the view page if already logged
        return;
        }

    if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
        // Redirect the browser to index.php
        header("Location: index.php");
        return;}


    /*
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    // to save the name for the next page
    }
    */

    $_SESSION['comp']=false;
    $salt = 'XyZzy12*_';
    $stored_hash = hash('md5', 'XyZzy12*_php123'); //the hash of the password php123 with some salt on it 


    if(isset($_POST['login'])){  //when login is pressed

        $check = hash('md5', $salt . $_POST['pwd']); // to store the inserted password and compare it with the one that already stored\

        if(strlen($_POST['name']) < 1 ||strlen($_POST['email']) < 1 ||strlen($_POST['name']) < 1 ){
            // if the inputs are empty redirect to login.php
            $_SESSION['error'] = "PLEASE don't leave any blank fields";
            }

        elseif($check != $stored_hash){
            $_SESSION['error'] = "incorrect password";
            error_log("Login failed with ".$_POST['email']." using the password ".$_POST['pwd']);
            //header("Location: login.php");
        }   
        else{
            $_SESSION['success'] = "you are logged in ";
            $_SESSION['comp']=true;
            $_SESSION['prs']  =  $_POST['name']; 

            error_log("Login success ".$_POST['email']);
            header("Location: view.php");
            //return;
        }
        if(isset($_POST["stay"])){$_SEESION['loged']=true;}
        }
    ?>


    <!--the view code-->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
        height: 1000px;
        background: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0000 0%, #ffcc00 100%);

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    h1{
        color : #000000;
        text-align : center;
        font-family: "SIMPSON";
    }

    form {
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }

    </style>
    <title>logging in ....</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">
    <h1> Log in please :</h1>
    <?php
        if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) {
            echo('<p align= "center" style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($_SESSION['error'])."</p>\n");
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
        }
        ?>

          <form method="POST" action="login.php" >
           <table>
           <tr>
             <td>Name :</td> <td><input type="text" maxlength="40" name="name"></td><br>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>Email :</td> <td><input type="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" ></td><br>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>Password :</td> <td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td><br>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td><td><input type="radio" name="stay" value="1"> remember me<br>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td></td> <td><input align ="center"  type="submit"  name="login" value="login"> <input align ="center" type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel"></td><br>
            </tr>

           </table>
          </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

so after entering the values and checking the radio box and submit to log in ,
and it should store some data in $_SESSION 
then the view page will be shown , but when i get back to the login.php page nothing is happening and the

```
header("location:view.php");
```

doesn't work .
any one help me and tell me where i can do edits to make it work i'm a beginner in php and that is a simple training project

Comment: Dont use MD5 it can be decrypted (brute forced) in a matter of minutes, Don't expose the users Password, which brings me to this how is this supposed to remember anyone when I don't see no Cookies in there.  I was going to say dont hash a users password and store it in a cookie but welp no cookies.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix it is just a training app but the main problem is that when i login to the view.php  and i go back to login.php it keeps asking me to login again even if i checked the remember me option

Comment: `it is just a training app`  Why would you wan't to "train" the wrong way?  Just wondering, as password_hash(), and password_verify() are very easy to use, easier then what you did above.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix tnx for your advises i will search on thous topics

Comment: Sure, its not problem I see so many people struggle with login scripts, and a lot of time not only are they insecure, but they are working to hard.  Probably working off of antiquated tutorials.  It's a very necessary thing (user persistence)  but 9 times out of 10 its done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `header("location:view.php");`

There is a typo in your code `header("location view.php");`

and `isset($_SESSION["comp"])` will be true for `$_SESSION["comp"]=false` as well

Check this http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Do: `if(isset($_SESSION["comp"]) && $_SESSION["comp"]==true)`

Comment: oh tnx a lot , but is their any tips for the radio box and how to make $_POST['stay'] work ??? because i  use print_r to print the session in the view page but i cant find the $_SESSION['loged'] any  where

Comment: if(isset($_POST["stay"])){$_SEESION['loged']=true;}
        } moved it to code block before header(location...

Comment: You redirect to view.php before setting this session and fulfilling this if condition.
do it after: $_SESSION['success'] = "you are logged in ";
            $_SESSION['comp']=true;
            $_SESSION['prs']  =  $_POST['name'];

Comment: do `if(!empty($_SESSION["comp"]))` empty doesn't give you an error for undefined variables and it sees falsy values as empty.

Comment: As a beginner, a basic debug tip is to do an echo 'ok'; exit; to see till where you can reach in your code. Are you even reaching the code intended to do the function you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your view.php page with `session_start()` as the first thing also. Anywhere that you want to use sessions, you have to declare it.

```
    <?php
session_start();
```

Comment: im using session_start(); in view.php but when i get back to login.php from view.php it ask's me to login again even if i checked the remember me option

Comment: Because you don't have no cookies, I like oatmeal ones myself.  Let me explain the session has a cookie normally its something like PHPSESSID, which is how the site remembers your session, however the session is usually set to about 30 minutes, you need to store some data (not a password) in a cookie of your making, and then you have persistent storage on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Well your header location tag is wrong for one thing

```
header("location view.php");
```

Should be

```
header("location: view.php");
```

Then this `return` outside of a function scope is really bugging me, lol.  It just looks semantically wrong.  I would use `exit` as it typically done.

Of course that might just be a typo in the question, testing that local I get this

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at **admin@localhost** to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server **error log**.

Should I contact them and let them know about it J/P

Use `empty` instead of `isset` to check boolean values.

```
 $foo = false;
 var_dump(isset($foo));  //true - it is set
 var_dump(empty($foo));  //true - it is empty
```

Logically empty is the opposite of isset. Where you check isset you would check not empty. I just didn't want the double negative.

Then if it's undefined (either one wont issue an error)

```
 var_dump(isset($foo));  //false- it is not set
 var_dump(empty($foo));  //true - it is still empty
```

In other words if (these two conditions are logically equivalent):

```
  $foo = false;
  if(isset($foo)) //passes
  if(!empty($foo)) //fails


  //$foo = false;  <-- when its not set
  if(isset($foo)) //fails
  if(!empty($foo)) //fails  (fails if its false and if its not set)
```

So applying that to your code:

```
  if(isset($_SESSION["comp"])){
       header("location view.php");//to redirect to the view page if already logged
       return;
  }
  ...
  $_SESSION['comp']=false;
```

When you load the page the next time, `$_SESSION['comp']` is false, but it is also set, so the if condition will pass.  However if you use empty, it will behave as you would expect it to.  Hopefully my explanation makes sense above, once you understand how it works it becomes obvious.

The problem with `empty` comes when it's used to check things like `''`, `[]` or `0` as PHP is loosely typed and will see these all as false, and emtpy.  It makes sense if you really think about it.  `[]` is an empty array, `''` is an empty string and `0` is an empty number.  But, it can trip you up if you think `empty = isset` as they do very different things.  Even though they are somewhat interchangeable.

**OTHER STUFF**

A remember me option only works one way, and that is to store a cookie in the clients browser.  The session uses it's own cookie, the default is something like PHPSESSID (We have netscape to thank for these).  To understand why you need a cookie you must understand that each request to the server is stateless, and anonymous.

Because there is no state, nor any way to (reliably) identify one client from another we use a cookie.  It's just a bit of data that says I am me that the server gives a client. Even though you can never trust anything from a client this gives us a way to have persistent storage on the client for the client, to identify them.

You can't use the session for remember me, because by design session life times are short, usually about 30 minutes.  Besides what would the point be, if their session never expired you'd never need a remember me option, and we wouldn't be talking (texting) about it.

There is a whole host of security concerns to deal with when making a "simple" remember me button.  To many for me to cover in a post on here.  That said doing it the right way really isn't much harder then doing it any other way.

Someday when I get my site put back together I plan to publish a full working User's system as a tutorial on it.  But as PHP5 is nearing extinction I have been to busy to do much of anything (besides fixing old sites).

Cheers.

Comment: @MosaAbbas - I should be I been programing professionally for almost a decade .. lol.